# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu<1.11.0,>=1.3.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, mask-rcnn

when I try to use mask-rcnn to train my datasets, and then I set environment first, and the tensorflow-gpu's version can't satisfy my need, and it showed like that ,how to fix it, thanks.
[image]

I want to know how to find a satisfied version for training.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install tensor flow-gpu specifying a version with pip or condo